# Add active class to 2 Bootstrap Carousels on same page with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 bootstrap carousels on 1 page (special-carousel and quote-carousel). Neither carousel has any active classes set as I want to set them with javascript. My javascript code works for the first carousel but not the 2nd. Both carousels use different ID's and I have tried duplicating the javascript code to target just the 2nd carousel but the slides do not display.

The first item within the second slider has 2 new classes added to it which are **next left** which are obviously wrong.

My javascript looks like this:

```
<!-- Code for special carousel -->
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $(".carousel-indicators li:first").addClass("active");
        $(".carousel-inner .item:first").addClass("active");
    });
</script>
```

```
<!-- Code for quote carousel -->
<script>
    (document).ready(function() {
        $(".carousel-indicators li:first").addClass("active");
        $(".carousel-inner .item:first").addClass("active");
    });
</script>
```

I've setup a demo page that shows the problem
http://handcoded.co.uk/carousel.html

How can I target the 2nd carousel so that active classes are added to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your javascript code, your jquery selector are targeting the same carousel instance. You should narrow your selector like that :

```
<!-- Code for special carousel -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#special-carousel .carousel-indicators li:first").addClass("active");
  $("#special-carousel .carousel-inner .item:first").addClass("active");
});
</script>

<!-- Code for quote carousel -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#quote-carousel .carousel-indicators li:first").addClass("active");
  $("#quote-carousel .carousel-inner .item:first").addClass("active");
});
</script>
```

link to working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/11116/

Mind that there is some possible enhancement to your code, for e.g you can use only one document ready, cache jquery selector, etc